# JOIN with one column to get appropriate client names in two separate columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch Originating & Terminating customers in two different columns as per their Account IDs but my join is giving me the same result in the output columns.

All customers are in **vbClient.clCustomerID** column.

**Getting below Output:**

[image]

**Required Output:**

[image]

**Below is the tables output**
[image]

**Here is my query**

```
SELECT vbClient.clCustomerID 'Originating Customer', vbClient.clCustomerID 'Terminating Customer'
FROM Successfuliptsp.vbSuccessfulCDR_634, iTelBillingiptsp.vbClient
WHERE vbClient.clAccountID = vbSuccessfulCDR_634.orgClientAccountID
AND vbClient.clAccountID = vbSuccessfulCDR_634.terClientAccountID
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your raw data looks like

Comment: please share sample data

Comment: @CarloR Question edited with raw data

Comment: ```.. FROM vbSuccessfulCDR_634 AS t1 JOIN vbClient AS t2 ON t1.orgClientAccountID = t2.clAccountID JOIN vbClient AS t3 ON t1.terClientAccountID = t3.clAccountID ..```

Comment: @AmitVerma Question Edited with sample Data

Comment: @Akina Tried your solution but not working. Can you please try with the full query.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: *Tried your solution but not working.* Add your attempt to the question as an update.

Comment: @Akina .. SELECT vbClient.clCustomerID 'Originating Customer', vbClient.clCustomerID 'Terminating Customer'
FROM Successfuliptsp.vbSuccessfulCDR_634 AS t1 JOIN iTelBillingiptsp.vbClient AS t2
ON t1.orgClientAccountID = t2.clAccountID
JOIN iTelBillingiptsp.vbClient AS t3 ON t1.terClientAccountID = t3.clAccountID ..

Error Code: Unknown column 'vbClient.clCustomerID' in 'field list'

Comment: *Error Code: Unknown column 'vbClient.clCustomerID' in 'field list'* Please investigate what is "table/column name alias".

Comment: @Akina My posted code gives output for the same field but having error after adding yours...

Comment: @Akina Able to see the output now but still getting same data in two output columns but should show the client name as per matching AccountID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t2.clCustomerID AS `Originating Customer`, 
       t3.clCustomerID AS `Terminating Customer` 
FROM Successfuliptsp.vbSuccessfulCDR_634 AS t1 
JOIN iTelBillingiptsp.vbClient AS t2 ON t1.orgClientAccountID = t2.clAccountID 
JOIN iTelBillingiptsp.vbClient AS t3 ON t1.terClientAccountID = t3.clAccountID
```